# trigger in rules a beep sound on user side (current user is working)

Tags: 7, rules

I have a D7 site running with Organic groups, rules, VBO, panels, badges, private-message modules ... and a bootstrap sub-theme (js, jQuery update, ...) working in all browsers, ios & android, i need to alert users with a beep sound when new OG content is created (or any rules reaction) by a custom module named beepsound module.

What I have:

•   Rules event: create new content

•   Rules condition: my contentype with some fields.

•   Rules action: Loop: all OG group members, loop action: see code below

"beepsound module" must have UID variable to target a specific OG member.

I have manage to have my beepsound as an action in rules, it targets UID, it display a personalised message corectly, also, message is displayed 5 times (when tiggered when mycontentype is being viewed), meaning rule is triggered 5 times, here are my-module code files, dot module file exist but is empty (and not displayed here), If i run this rule with current-user, it works (makes a beep), but not in my OG loop, what it is wrong?

beepsound.info MODULE

```
name = Beep sound by rules module 
description = Module to add a beep sound action in rules
package = Custom
version = 7.01
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = rules
```

beepsound.rules.inc MODULE

```
/**
* Implement hook_rules_action_info()
* Declare any meta data about actions for Rules
*/

function beepsound_rules_action_info() {
$actions = array(
'beepsound_action_beepsound_user' => array(
    'label' => t('Make a beep sound'),
    'group' => t('sound'),
    'parameter' => array(
        'account' => array(
            'type' => 'user',
            'label' => t('User to beep'),
            ),
    ),
  ),

);

  return $actions;
}

/**
 * The action function for produce sound
 */

function beepsound_action_beepsound_user($account) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Hello @username',
 array('@username' => $account->name)));
    ?><audio autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="/sites/all/modules/beepsound/A-tone.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="/sites/all/modules/beepsound/A-Tone.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio><?php
}
```

here is my rule

```
{ "og_og_new_content_notification_message" : {
"LABEL" : "OG new content notification message",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "OG" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "og", "rules", "privatemsg_rules", "beepsound" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert" : [] },
"IF" : [ { "og_entity_is_group_content" : { "entity" : [ "node" ] } } ],
"DO" : [
  { "og_get_members" : {
      "USING" : { "group_content" : [ "node" ] },
      "PROVIDE" : { "group_members" : { "group_members" : "List of group members" } }
    }
  },
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "group-members" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "privatemsg_rules_new" : {
            "USING" : {
              "recipient" : [ "list-item" ],
              "author" : [ "node:author" ],
              "subject" : "\u0022[node:title]\u0022 a sido creado. ",
              "body" : "\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E Por favor haz clic aqu\u00ed para ver su contenido\u003C\/a\u003E"
            },
            "PROVIDE" : { "thread_id" : { "thread_id" : "ID of new thread" } }
          }
        },
        { "beepsound_action_beepsound_user" : { "account" : [ "list-item" ] } },
        { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "beep beep, usuario: \u0022[list-item:uid]\u0022" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Se ha enviado un mensaje a todos los miembros del departamento." } }
]
```

}
}

Comment: Hi, we can't help you to decide which method you want to use, but once you have, and if you're struggling to implement that method with rules, please ask a specific question about that. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to send a message to users other than the current user, you will need to do some additional processing. `drupal_set_message` sets a message in the current user session. It does not set a message in another user's session.

Some possible approaches include a push or pull notification type system.
For example, the server can push updates to the client using something interesting like a [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-03?hl=en) ([advanced](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en)). Alternatively, the client can poll the server periodically, via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) type request to get message updates.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. Can you please be more specific? I understand that "rules" are on server side, and my "beep sound" is on user side.

Comment: Hi @pinueve, you may need to be more specific with your question.